# KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents

Tags: keycloak

I'm running Keycloak 6.0.1 in high availability using postgres as the database.

I'm seeing the following error (I've included the warnings before and after) in my Keycloak logs.

It appears that login fails just before this log is shown. If this is the cause, I would expect this to be the other way around.

Could this error stop a user being able to log in?

Is there a way that I can prevent this error from occurring?

I am seeing this error 10s (maybe even 100) times a day.

I've included the datasources section of standalone-ha.xml

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] (Transaction Reaper Worker 419) HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012110: TransactionReaper::check successfuly marked TX 0:ffff0a2a0635:-3e8bd89a:608740f2:4d0eba as rollback only
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 419) ARJUNA012113: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 419,5,main] missed interrupt when cancelling TX 0:ffff0a2a0635:-3e8bd89a:608740f2:4d0eba -- exiting as zombie (zombie count decremented to 0)
ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (Timer-2) KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!
  at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
  at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1599)
  at org.keycloak.events.jpa.JpaEventStoreProvider.clear(JpaEventStoreProvider.java:71)
  at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClearExpiredEvents.run(ClearExpiredEvents.java:37)
  at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1.call(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:56)
  at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1.call(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:52)
  at org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.InfinispanClusterProvider.executeIfNotExecuted(InfinispanClusterProvider.java:78)
  at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.runTask(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:52)
  at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner.run(ScheduledTaskRunner.java:45)
  at org.keycloak.timer.basic.BasicTimerProvider$1.run(BasicTimerProvider.java:51)
  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
  at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!
  at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl.processAnyDelayedAfterCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl.java:90)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delayedAfterCompletion(SessionImpl.java:656)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1536)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1612)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1589)
  ... 10 more
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Timer-2) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff0a2a0635:-3e8bd89a:608740f2:4d0eba




<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_ADDR:postgres}:${env.DB_PORT:5432}/${env.DB_DATABASE:keycloak}${env.JDBC_PARAMS:}</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql</driver>
        <pool>
            <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>${env.DB_USER:keycloak}</user-name>
            <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD:password}</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
            <background-validation>true</background-validation>
            <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
        </validation>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem....were you able to find the solution ?
Also during this time, our offline token creation/refresh requests get failed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not the answer; but a summary of the same problem as I face it. Hoping many different view-points will bring us up to the speed for finding a resolution.

Keycloak version 19.0.2

During intervals I get an IllegalAccessError error in the console:

Summary:

```
Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents: 
ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1 tried to access protected field
```

Detailed trace:

```
05:36:25,439 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1 tried to access protected field 
org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner.task (org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1 is in unnamed module of loader 
'org.keycloak.keycloak-model-legacy-private@19.0.2' @1dd488e6; org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner is in unnamed module of loader 'org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@19.0.2' @3c5c0acd)
```

Reported on Keycloak JIRA: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/KEYCLOAK/issues/KEYCLOAK-19949